# Upsampling tweets using SMOTE

Tags: scikit-learn, oversampling, smote

I have an imbalanced dataset of tweets labeled as -1, 0, +1.
I wanna balance the numbers by upsampling. I receive the following error:

```
tweet_train=tweet_train.reshape(-1, 1)
X_train_upsample, y_train_upsample = SMOTE(random_state=42).fit_sample(tweet_train, y_train)
```

> could not convert string to float: 'از این به بعد همینهسلبریتی هایی که ایدیولوژی های #جمهوری_اسلامی رو تبلیغ می کنن خارج از مرز ایران هم حق ندارن آسایش داشته باشن و مجبور بود#باش همچنان ادا وفاداری به اون ایدیولوژی رو در بیارن چون هر جا یه دوربین منتظره که #ریاکاری شون رو ثبت کنه '

Why should it event try to turn the string into float?

PS. prior to reshaping, tweet_train and y_train are numpy arrays with shape=(n,)

Answer (score 1):

You need to vectorize your data first: For instance you can represent a tweet by a vector of dimensions the same size as the number of words in the vocabulary. The values are the number of occurrences of the word (= column) in the document.

Comment: That would work but I think it wouldn't be the most correct way. I may cause over-fitting

Comment: SMOTE needs vectors of real values as input to generate new instances. I took the bag of words approach only as an example of vectorization. There are several other ways to vectorize text, such as Paragraph Vector embeddings for instance. But you cannot feed strings since SMOTE doesn't know how to deal with them (It seems from the error you get that ``tweet_train`` contains strings.).

Comment: I understand your point. But I'm saying that our BOW representation changes after over-sampling. If we first create BOW and then over-sample, it won't be as accurate. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I never tried to apply SMOTE for textual data. Maybe it is better to just duplicate tweets from the minority class without generating synthetic ones.